# Strange behavior of tuple indexing a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I noticed some confusing behavior when indexing a flat numpy array with a list of tuples (using python 2.7.8 and numpy 1.9.1). My guess is that this is related to the maximum number of array dimensions (which I believe is 32), but I haven't been able to find the documentation.

```
>>> a = np.arange(100)
>>> tuple_index = [(i,) for i in a]
>>> a[tuple_index] # This works (but maybe it shouldn't)
>>> a[tuple_index[:32]] # This works too
>>> a[tuple_index[:31]] # This breaks for 2 <= i < 32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
>>> a[tuple_index[:1]] # This also works...
```

Is the list of tuples is being "flattened" if it is 32 elements or larger? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Interesting, I get a different error message: `IndexError: unsupported iterator index`. Using python 2.7 and numpy 1.8.2

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified the versions (python 2.7.8; numpy 1.9.1). I've updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference appears to be that the first examples trigger fancy indexing (which simply selects indices in a list from the same dimension) whereas `tuple_index[:31]` is instead treated as an indexing tuple (which implies selection from multiple axes).

As you noted, the maximum number of dimensions for a NumPy array is (usually) 32:

```
>>> np.MAXDIMS
32
```

According to the following comment in the [mapping.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1f6e7cc470c6d5af23b2467863f42108e6c5f545/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#l198) file (which contains the code to interpret the index passed by the user), any sequence of tuples shorter than 32 is flattened to an indexing tuple:

```C
/*
 * Sequences < NPY_MAXDIMS with any slice objects
 * or newaxis, Ellipsis or other arrays or sequences
 * embedded, are considered equivalent to an indexing
 * tuple. (`a[[[1,2], [3,4]]] == a[[1,2], [3,4]]`)
 */
```

(I haven't yet found a reference for this in the official documentation on the SciPy site.)

This makes `a[tuple_index[:3]]` equivalent to `a[(0,), (1,), (2,)]`, hence the "too many indices" error (because `a` has only one dimension but we're implying there are three).

On the other hand, `a[tuple_index]` is just the same as `a[[(0,), (1,), (2,), ..., (99,)]]` resulting in the 2D array.

Comment: The [basics documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) claims that *Index arrays must be of integer type.* Apparently the implementation allows this anyway. What I still can't figure out is why you get a 2D array from the list of tuples greater than `np.MAXDIMS`.

Comment: I agree it doesn't seem obvious (and I don't know if it's intended or not). When longer than `MAXDIMS` [it looks like](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1f6e7cc470c6d5af23b2467863f42108e6c5f545/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#l395) the list of tuples `[(0,), (1,),  (2,) ..., (99,)]` is internally cast to a NumPy array (it will become a 2D array). This is then used to index the original 1D array (returning a 2D array).